# After log4j changes Hive -e returns additional warning which has impact on the scripts - WARN JNDI lookup class is not available because this JRE

Tags: hive, log4j, cloudera

In project we use some technical scripts in python with usage of Subprocess to extract some data from hive, run msck repair table etc ( I know we should switch to beeline :p) unfortunately after the issue with log4j in every output we started to get something like this:

WARN JNDI lookup class is not available because this JRE does not support JNDI. JNDI string lookups will not be available, continuing configuration. Ignoring java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.JndiLookup

Our Infra team is not allowing us so far to introduce any changes in the log4j properties.

As we have multiple technical scripts in many places we would like to find simple solution for time being (till we can fix it on infra level).

Tried:
usage hive -s
settings hive.root.looger to console (I think somehow log4j does not understand this is warning)

Guys does anyone know how we can fix it (preferably during runtime)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way to fix this is to patch your `log4j-core` with a nerfed version of `JndiLookup` rather then removing the class entirely with `zip -d ...`. A simple version of that class could look something like this:

```java
package org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LogEvent;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.Plugin;

@Plugin(name = "jndi", category = StrLookup.CATEGORY)
public class JndiLookup extends AbstractLookup {
    @Override
    public String lookup(final LogEvent event, final String key) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here's a gist with a bash script that automates the compile and replace process:

https://gist.github.com/xyu/348e9cecf25e09bef997a58e1901481b

Answer (score 0):

I looked at what changes were introduced to JndiLookup.java from version 2.0 through 2.14.1 (just before the 2.15 release). No significant changes. It appears regardless of what log4j2 version your application is using you can craft a JndiLookup.java mock class that simply calls LOGGER.warn and nothing else when JndiLookup.lookup is called. You would then replace JndiLookup.class instead of removing it from the jar. The class will load, but do nothing of meaning besides give you a log message you can monitor in your application logs, if doing so adds value.

```
$git diff rel/2.0 rel/2.14.1 log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/JndiLookup.java
diff --git a/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/JndiLookup.java b/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/JndiLookup.java
index 77749e015..30e65ad24 100644
--- a/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/JndiLookup.java
+++ b/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/JndiLookup.java
@@ -16,53 +16,47 @@
  */
 package org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup;
 
-import javax.naming.Context;
-import javax.naming.InitialContext;
+import java.util.Objects;
+
 import javax.naming.NamingException;
 
+import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
+import org.apache.logging.log4j.Marker;
+import org.apache.logging.log4j.MarkerManager;
 import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LogEvent;
 import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.Plugin;
-import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.Closer;
+import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.JndiManager;
+import org.apache.logging.log4j.status.StatusLogger;
 
 /**
  * Looks up keys from JNDI resources.
  */
-@Plugin(name = "jndi", category = "Lookup")
-public class JndiLookup implements StrLookup {
+@Plugin(name = "jndi", category = StrLookup.CATEGORY)
+public class JndiLookup extends AbstractLookup {
 
-    /** JNDI resourcce path prefix used in a J2EE container */
-    static final String CONTAINER_JNDI_RESOURCE_PATH_PREFIX = "java:comp/env/";
+    private static final Logger LOGGER = StatusLogger.getLogger();
+    private static final Marker LOOKUP = MarkerManager.getMarker("LOOKUP");
 
-    /**
-     * Looks up the value of the JNDI resource.
-     * @param key  the JNDI resource name to be looked up, may be null
-     * @return The value of the JNDI resource.
-     */
-    @Override
-    public String lookup(final String key) {
-        return lookup(null, key);
-    }
+    /** JNDI resource path prefix used in a J2EE container */
+    static final String CONTAINER_JNDI_RESOURCE_PATH_PREFIX = "java:comp/env/";
 
     /**
      * Looks up the value of the JNDI resource.
      * @param event The current LogEvent (is ignored by this StrLookup).
      * @param key  the JNDI resource name to be looked up, may be null
-     * @return The value of the JNDI resource.
+     * @return The String value of the JNDI resource.
      */
     @Override
     public String lookup(final LogEvent event, final String key) {
         if (key == null) {
             return null;
         }
-
-        Context ctx = null;
-        try {
-            ctx = new InitialContext();
-            return (String) ctx.lookup(convertJndiName(key));
+        final String jndiName = convertJndiName(key);
+        try (final JndiManager jndiManager = JndiManager.getDefaultManager()) {
+            return Objects.toString(jndiManager.lookup(jndiName), null);
         } catch (final NamingException e) {
+            LOGGER.warn(LOOKUP, "Error looking up JNDI resource [{}].", jndiName, e);
             return null;
-        } finally {
-            Closer.closeSilently(ctx);
         }
     }
 
@@ -73,11 +67,10 @@ public class JndiLookup implements StrLookup {
      * @param jndiName The name of the resource.
      * @return The fully qualified name to look up.
      */
-    private String convertJndiName(String jndiName) {
+    private String convertJndiName(final String jndiName) {
         if (!jndiName.startsWith(CONTAINER_JNDI_RESOURCE_PATH_PREFIX) && jndiName.indexOf(':') == -1) {
-            jndiName = CONTAINER_JNDI_RESOURCE_PATH_PREFIX + jndiName;
+            return CONTAINER_JNDI_RESOURCE_PATH_PREFIX + jndiName;
         }
-
         return jndiName;
     }
 }
```